# can someone explain the python code to me, I don't understand

Tags: python, parameters, reference, arguments, pass-by-reference

```py
def all_aboard(a, *args, **kw):
    print(a, args, kw)

all_aboard(4, 7, 3, 0, x=10, y=64)
```

I want to know how this works as the output of the program is

```
4 (7, 3, 0) {'x': 10, 'y': 64}
```

How is the code computed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all_aboard` parameters are:

1. `a` - you already know it
2. `*args` - any number of parameters which are set as tuple
3. `**kw` - give you all keyword arguments except for those corresponding to a formal parameter as a dictionary

For this reason the output is:

```
4 (7, 3, 0) {'x': 10, 'y': 64}
```

since `a = 4`, `*args = (7, 3, 0)` and `**kw = {'x': 10, 'y': 64}`